# How to read pfx file's thumbprint without prompt for password

Tags: powershell, ssl, openssl, certificate, x509

I have a need to obtain a thumbprint from a pfx file on the ***filesystem*** without being prompted for a password that requires manual input.

I'm running this as part of an installer where the user specifies the path to the certificate on the filesystem (Not in the store). And the user specifies the password for the certificate. From that point, i need the thumbprint.

So this is simply a matter of discovering a tool which i can pass a path and password to a pfx file and return the thumbprint.  I've tried several tools, but even OpenSSL compiled for windows, and it still prompts for the password and gives back a lot more info than just the thumbprint. It needs to be 100% programmatic and without further user intervention.

I'd love to hear any ideas on how to do this. This will be on Windows Server machines only. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this - it involves downloading  OpenSSL for windows and using that tool to convert and using powershell to read it out.

**Conversion**

```
& openssl pkcs12 -in C:\LocalHost.pfx -out C:\mycertificates.crt -nokeys -clcerts -passin pass:ActualPassword
```

**Read In**

```
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("C:\mycertificates.crt")
$thumbprint = $cert.Thumbprint

write-host $thumbprint
```

So i had to convert to crt/cer first and then read using X509Certificate2.

Comment: And you have used the password to convert it.That doesn't answer the question

Comment: @bradgonesurfing I think you misread the question -- he had the password from a previous installer step, he just wanted to open it without PROMPTing for it.

Answer (score 1):

When creating .pfx (pkcs#12) file, the internal storage containers, called "SafeBags", may also be encrypted and signed.

By default, OpenSSL encrypts the certificate along with its private key, which means **it is not possible** to get its thumbprint without knowing password.

When creating a *new* pfx, you can explicitly add `-certpbe NONE` to avoid encrypting the certificate.
For more details check `-certpbe` [OpenSSL's man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkcs12)